# I'm trying to send input data to ASP.NET Core backend using reactive form and formdata

Tags: angular, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning about how to use reactive form with formData all I have is reactive form which has couple of input fields which also take Image as input, and used form data to append

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqIu5.png)

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit(myForm.value)">
    <div>
        <label>Area : 
            <input formControlName="area">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>CountryName : 
            <input formControlName="countryName">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Population : 
            <input formControlName="population">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Image :
        </label>
        <input type="file" formControlName="Image" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[console.log frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qRn.png)

[typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HugZu.png)

```
export class AddDataComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile!: File;
  baseUrl: any = "https://localhost:7044";
  myForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      area: new FormControl(''),
      countryName: new FormControl(''),
      population: new FormControl(''),
      Image: new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
    })
  }
  onSelectFile(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      this.selectedFile=<File> event.target.files[0];
  }
}

  formSubmit(data: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('area',data.area);
    formData.append('countryName',data.countryName);
    formData.append('population',data.population);
    formData.append('Image', this.selectedFile);
    for (const value of formData.values()) {
      console.log(value);
    }
    this.http.post<Data>(this.baseUrl + '/api/controller/addData', formData).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log(`response received ${res}`);
        this.router.navigate(['home'])
        alert('data added');
      }
    })
  }
}
```

[ASP.NET Core Web API model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXqAP.png)

```
namespace filtering.Models
{
    public class population
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryName {get;set;}
        public string Area { get; set;} 
        public int Population { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Controller with error (click on me to see error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4KEH.png)

```
    [HttpPost("addData")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> addPopulation([FromForm] population population)
    {
        population.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        population.CountryName = population.CountryName.ToLower();
        population.Area = population.Area.ToLower();
        await _populationDbContext.population.AddAsync(population);
        await _populationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(population);
    }
```

When I try to submit form ,"HttpPost" in backend my input parameter i.e population object is empty, so can you guys please guide me ?

BTW I am using angular for frontend, for backend ASP.NET Core Web API and EF Core for connection with postgres server

I was expecting that I want to store the uploaded image along with input field using EF Core

Comment: You could follow this demo that post formdata contains file  on github :https://github.com/SinghDigamber/angular-formdata.git

Answer (score 0):

First you can send the input model to the form included in the view model. Then fill the input to in to the form and send it to the rost action back.

Controller action send view model to the form

```
public class InputModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string BikeType { get; set; }

    public string BikeTypeDesctiption { get; set; }

    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddBike()
{
     var viewModel = new MyViewModel
     {
         BikeModel = viewModel,
         InputModel = inputModel,
     }

     return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

Form send input model to the controller action

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    // text input
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <label asp-for="InputModel.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="InputModel.Name" class="form-control" value="Suzuki"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="InputModel.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    // dropdown, can receive data from the view model too 
    <div class="col-md-7">

        <label asp-for="InputModel.BikeType"></label>

        <select asp-for="InputModel.BikeType" class="form-control">
            <option value="Naked">Naked</option>
            <option value="Cruiser">Cruiser</option>
            <option value="Adventure">Adventure</option>
            <option value="Tourer">Tourer</option>
            <option value="Enduro">Enduro</option>
            <option value="Grom">Grom</option>
            <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
        </select>

        <span asp-validation-for="InputModel.BikeType" class="text-danger"></span>

    </div>

    // text area
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <label asp-for="InputModel.BikeTypeDesctiption"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="InputModel.BikeTypeDesctiption" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="InputModel.BikeTypeDesctiption" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    // file input
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <label asp-for="InputModel.Image"></label>
        <input asp-for="InputModel.Image" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="InputModel.Image" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4" />

</form>
```

Controller action receive input model from form

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddBike(InputModel input)
{
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        // validate image if needed
        if (input.Image != null)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + ("/images/bikes/" + input.Model + input.EngineCapacity + "-1" + ".jpg"), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await input.Image.CopyToAsync(fs);
            }
        }
        
        // save result
        await this.motorBikesService.AddBikeAsync(input);

        return this.RedirectToAction(nameof(this.Success));
}
```